# Android: enable/disable app widgets programmatically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-widget, android-appwidget

**Question**: Is there a way to enable some of the homescreen widgets that I give out with my app programmatically? For example, having a "premium" widget and giving access to it only after payment?

---

As the Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) say, one should add a broadcast receiver in the manifest to tell the system that there is a widget coming with the app:

```
<receiver android:name="ExampleAppWidgetProvider" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
           android:resource="@xml/example_appwidget_info" />
</receiver>
```

But in theory broadcast receivers can also be added programmatically, so can the widgets be registered later at runtime?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can have `android:enabled="false"` on the `<receiver>` element for the app widget in the manifest, then use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to enable it at runtime when the the user does something (e.g., pay up).

However, it is possible that this will require a reboot before the home screen realizes that there is a new potential app widget provider.

Comment: Thanks! A short question to it: does this mean that other apps can call this function specifying my receiver component or even enable it from adb command line?

Comment: @frangulyan: "does this mean that other apps can call this function specifying my receiver component" -- ordinary Android SDK apps cannot. System apps, apps on rooted devices, etc. might. "even enable it from adb command line?" -- I think so. IMHO, that should be fairly far down your list of concerns.

Comment: Late to the party, I know, but for future reference `setComponentEnabledSetting()` doesn't reliably work for AppWidgets on all Android versions. Bug report is here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36914010

Comment: not working.. on run time it does not enable receiver

Comment: @String Now the bug is fixed!!

Comment: @kelvin do you have a reference for the fix? I still experience some issue, especially Android 11 and below.

Answer (score 6):

```
PackageManager packageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
//To disable widget
packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyAppWidgetProvider.class), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
//To enable widget
packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyAppWidgetProvider.class), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to the shared code snippet.

Comment: it works.. but it takes some time to disable widget

Comment: App crash, Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component class does not exist.