# Is there a way to put Android App widget behind a feature toggle?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack

I have App Widgets that I built for my application and I wanted to put them behind a feature toggle until they're ready to go in production. Is that possible with Widget App since they're like Services. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40070380

Answer (score 0):

As @Mike M. posted a link above. Just reposting the answer here. Setting android:enabled = "false" seems to disable it.

```
   <receiver android:name=".widget.DemoWidget"
            android:enabled="false">

        </receiver>
```